# Switch CSS background colour on hover and on click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, onhover

I have been using this script to switch CSS background colour on click and I've been trying to change it so the second colour will appear on hover and the will appear on click. Can anyone help to get this to work?

Here is my jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/pkrWV/70/

```
var bodyObj, className, index;

bodyObj = document.getElementById('body');
index = 1;
className = [
    'imageOne',
    'imageTwo',
     'imageThree',
];

function updateIndex(){
    if(index === 0){
        index = 1;
    }else{
        index = 0;
    }
}

bodyObj.onclick = function(e){
    e.currentTarget.className = className[index];
    updateIndex();
}
```

Comment: James you have 15 rep and the ability to upvote. Use it. You have 5 good answers and each one deserves one. Costs nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color to change on hover, you just need to define [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) selector for your class. Like this -

```
#body.imageOne:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```js
var bodyObj, className, index;

bodyObj = document.getElementById('body');
index = 1;
className = [
  'imageOne',
  'imageTwo',
  'imageThree',
];

function updateIndex() {
  if (index === 0) {
    index = 1;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
}

bodyObj.onclick = function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.className = className[index];
  updateIndex();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#body.imageOne {
  background-color: green;
}
/*Add this */

#body.imageOne:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
#body.imageTwo {
  background-color: red;
}
#body.imageThree {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" class="imageOne"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color on hover using javascript add:

```
bodyObj.onmouseover = function(e){
    e.currentTarget.className = className[2];
    updateIndex();
}
```

here is the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pkrWV/82/

I would recommend doing this through css :hover if possible

```
#body:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For mouse over use :hover state as previously mentioned. Capturing the onclick event to alter CSS happens to quickly. You can use the :active state which also happens very quickly and returns back with little to be seen by the user. The :visited state will override the browser default purple color they use for previously visited links. Though changing the state of a visited link away from the default can present usability concerns for your users as it will present a less familiar state for them.

Ex: styles.css

```
a { 
    color: black; 
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
a:active {
    color: gold;
}
a:visited {
    color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mange to do this using jQuery 2.1.3 
Here's the Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/pkrWV/109

html

```
<div id="body" class="imageOne">
    <button id="button" onclick="">Change</button>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#button").hover(function(){
    $("#body").css("background-color", "red");
});

$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#body").css("background-color", "green");
});

$("#button").mouseout(function(){
    $("#body").css("background-color", "gray");
});
```

css

```
html, body, #body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were looking for a jquery way of doing it. This is a blank screen to begin with. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkrWV/110/)

```js
$("#color").mouseleave(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "black");
});
$("#color").mouseover(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "red");
});
$("#color").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "green");
});
```

```css
body,
#color {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color">&nbsp;</div>
```